# HBase Cluster: org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative()V

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cluster-computing

I'm new to HBase. I'm running a HBase cluster on 2 machines (1 master on one machine and 1 regionserver on the second).

When I start the hbase shell using:

```
bin/hbase shell
```

and I create a table using this syntax:

```
create 't1', 'f1'
```

I get the following errors:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hduser/hbase-0.98.8-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-      1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.4/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative()V
```

I'm using HBase version 0.98.8-hadoop2 and my Hadoop version is Hadoop 1.0.4. And I'm running this on an Ubuntu Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 1):

I think `HBase-98.8` recent one won't support or won't work on `hadoop-1.x.x` . And if you have time just make sure this which all requirements were explained in a book `HBase: The Definitive Guide George, Lars` or just have look this [site](http://hbase.apache.org/book/configuration.html#hadoop)

Comment: Which version of `Hadoop` will `HBase-0.98.8` work on?

Comment: Hbase-0.98.8 supports hadoop-2.2.x onwards, better download latest stable version of hadoop.