# Spark is throwing UnsatisfiedLinkError error

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark

I'm running a clustered vagrant setup where I have ubuntu 14.04 and java 8 installed on my master and slave machines. My cluster successfully starts up with the slaves able to connect, however I'm not running hadoop. Instead I'm running the standalone version of spark 1.2.1.

I then copied the basic SparkPi example and compiled it with this pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>dev.quant</groupId>
  <artifactId>neural-spark</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
  <description>My wonderfull scala app</description>
  <inceptionYear>2010</inceptionYear>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>My License</name>
      <url>http://....</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.tools.version>2.10</scala.tools.version>
    <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs2_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>3.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-SNAP4</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.0</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
        <configuration>
          <useFile>false</useFile>
          <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
          <!-- If you have classpath issue like NoDefClassError,... -->
          <!-- useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar -->
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.*</include>
            <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>dev.quant.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Which works -> mvn -U clean scala:compile assembly:single

The program I run is:

```
package dev.quant

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

import scala.math._

/**
 * @author ${user.name}
 */

object App {

  def foo(x : Array[String]) = x.foldLeft("")((a,b) => a + b)

  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Pi").setMaster("spark://10.0.0.2:7077").set("spark.executor.memory",".5g")
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
    val slices = 20
    val n = math.min(100000L * slices, Int.MaxValue).toInt // avoid overflow
    val count = spark.parallelize(1 until n, slices).map { i =>
        val x = random * 2 - 1
        val y = random * 2 - 1
        if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0
      }.reduce(_ + _)
    println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n)
    spark.stop()
  }

}
```

So basically after running -> mvn scala:run -DmainClass=dev.quant.App I get the following error bellow...

```
15/03/04 22:46:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: dev
15/03/04 22:46:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: dev
15/03/04 22:46:15 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(dev); users with modify permissions: Set(dev)
15/03/04 22:46:16 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/03/04 22:46:16 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/03/04 22:46:16 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.0.2:50662]
15/03/04 22:46:16 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 50662.
15/03/04 22:46:16 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/03/04 22:46:16 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/03/04 22:46:16 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/spark-b8515bff-2915-4bc2-a917-fdb7c11849b5/spark-3527d111-3aac-4378-b493-17c92b394018
15/03/04 22:46:16 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 265.1 MB
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getSparkOrYarnConfig(Utils.scala:1873)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.<init>(BlockManager.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.<init>(BlockManager.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:240)
    at dev.quant.App$.main(App.scala:18)
    at dev.quant.App.main(App.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(UserGroupInformation.java:283)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.<init>(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.<init>(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.<clinit>(SparkHadoopUtil.scala)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:129)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative()V
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.<clinit>(JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.<init>(JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.java:38)
    ... 27 more
```

I've also tried just submitting the jar via ./spark-submit /path/to/my-jar but no avail. I have never seen this error before, but my first impression is that JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback is some java library that my binary spark distribution depends on, but java 8 doesn't have it. Anyway, let me know if you guys have any idea what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative()V
```

might be the cause of your problem. You might need to use the correct and compatible version of hadoop.

Relative thread: [HBase Cluster: org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative()V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351025/hbase-cluster-org-apache-hadoop-security-jnibasedunixgroupsmapping-anchornative)

Comment: Spark says I don't have to use hadoop. So I'm not sure why it's throwing such an error.

Comment: @Dr.Knowitall Spark's filesystem and security API is built on top of Hadoop APIs